# where nodeid is newest if not title copy from nodeid with same content id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I write a php file to show last post from my database.
I find last post but some last post have not title
I want show last post and ech post that have not the title copy from post that have title and is same contentid.my database is larg. i prepare a pic that is example of my database

[the example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD7JT.jpg)

this is my `php` code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "vbtest";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT title , nodeid FROM node where contenttypeid='30' order by nodeid desc limit 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "title: " . $row["nodeid"]. " title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: I don't understand why you want 9.

Comment: i have not error.i have the result that some of them have not title becouse one of them is first post and have title and other are answer to the first post and have not title.i want to show last post and show title of first post insted of title of first post.i hope you undrestant my problem.

Comment: "9" is last node id and when have contenttype 30 means that is a post.then 9 is last post node id.can you undrestant?

Comment: sorry i wrong write 9.the exact id is 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, how to leave only one unique title and first nodeid with sort.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT T.title,
       MIN(nodeid) AS nodeid
FROM
    (SELECT
           (SELECT N2.title FROM node AS N2
            WHERE N2.contentid = N.contentid
                  AND N2.starter = N.starter
            ORDER BY N2.nodeid ASC
            LIMIT 1) AS title,
            nodeid
    FROM node AS N
    WHERE contentid='30' 
    ORDER BY nodeid DESC LIMIT 10) AS T
GROUP BY title 
) AS T2
ORDER BY nodeid DESC
```

Comment: this work but ordering new nodeid to old nodeid is not right and is no order

Comment: What nodeid do you need in the group with similar title?

Comment: I've added sort operator in SQL query.

Comment: A thousand times thank you.You've answered me.patiently.i hope in future you help me again.

Answer (score 0):

I think subquery will help to archive your goal. In the SQL query below subquery will find first title for contentid from outer query.

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
       (SELECT N2.title FROM node AS N2
        WHERE N2.contentid = N.contentid
                  AND N2.starter = N.starter
        ORDER BY N2.nodeid ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS title,
        N.nodeid
FROM node AS N
WHERE contentid='30' 
ORDER BY nodeid DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Did you try my query?

Comment: i dont know many php code information.can you edit my code? i try your guery but error: ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: I found error, you need change contenttypeid to contentid. And I've created playground on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/402d4/3

Comment: thanks.i edit contenttypeid and wrror soloved but all of my result is same post and the post result order is from begin not from end.please note that this db is a egample and i used this code in a vbulletin database that have very post and title.can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean when you said "post result order is from begin not from end"? In my example nodeid with biggest number is first in result.

Comment: thanks a lot.this work for me.now i want to show ech title only one repeat. can i? example: test,test1,test3.  not test, test, test ,test1, test1, ...

Comment: But you have unique id in result table. So you can't use operator DISTINCT

Comment: If you don't need nodeid in result table your could rewrite your query as:
SELECT DISTINCT
       (SELECT N2.title FROM node AS N2
        WHERE N2.contentid = N.contentid
              AND N2.starter = N.starter
        ORDER BY N2.nodeid ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS title
FROM node AS N
WHERE contentid='30' 
ORDER BY nodeid DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: i use this example in my vbulletin db.but result is here:nodeid: 194702 title: vbulletin.org title
nodeid: 194701 title: vbulletin.org title
nodeid: 194700 title: the test topic
nodeid: 194699 title: the test topic
nodeid: 194697 title: http://localhost/vbman/member/1-vbpro
nodeid: 194696 title: ارور Sitemap file not found
nodeid: 194695 title: http://localhost/vbman/member/1-vbpro    i want to remode repeateed result.

Comment: As I understand you want remove repeated titles. Which nodeid do you need to stay in result table?

Comment: yes i want to remove repeated title from result.in other words i want to show ech title once time.if title is same previous not show !